# Tic Tac Toe: Winapi painting

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having trouble painting in my client area whenever I turn a bool true, trying to make a Tic Tac Toe, and once I get the initial painting properly I can keep going.

The main problem is that it is not painting the lower rows properly, or they are painted after a 3 or 4 click, At the moment I don't care about circles, just want to know what I am  have wrong.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        static BOOL fState[DIVISIONS][DIVISIONS];
        bool  XorO = false;
        static int  cxBlock, cyBlock;`

        HDC         hdc;
        int         x, y, iPosX , iPosY;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        RECT        rect;

        static const int grid = 1000;
        static const int block = grid / DIVISIONS;
        static const int width = 1200;
        static const int height =1200;

        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_SIZE:

                cxBlock = LOWORD (lParam) / DIVISIONS ;
                cyBlock = HIWORD (lParam) / DIVISIONS ;

            return 0;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            x = LOWORD(lParam)/ cxBlock;
            y = HIWORD(lParam)/cyBlock;

            if (x < DIVISIONS && y < DIVISIONS)
            {
                //Click in the first cuadrant x = 0 and y = 0 , so both false
                //second x = 1, y = 0
                //third x 2 , y = 0 and so on.
                fState[x][y] ^= 1;
                rect.left = x * block;
                rect.top = y * block;
                rect.right = (x + 1) * block;
                rect.bottom = (y + 1) * block;

                InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, FALSE);

            }
            else
                MessageBeep(0); 

            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:

            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);


            //paint X or ellipses here
            for (x = 0; x < DIVISIONS; x++)
                for (y = 0; y < DIVISIONS; y++)
                {

                    if (fState[x][y] )
                    {
                        MoveToEx(hdc, x     * block, y       *  block, NULL);
                        LineTo(hdc,  (x + 1) * block, (y + 1) *  block);
                        MoveToEx(hdc, x     * block, (y + 1) *  block, NULL);
                        LineTo(hdc,  (x + 1) * block, y       *  block);
                    }
                }


            //main grid
            for (int i = block; i < grid - 1; i += block) {
                MoveToEx(hdc, i, 0, NULL); 
                LineTo(hdc, i, grid);
                MoveToEx(hdc, 0, i, NULL);
                LineTo(hdc, grid, i);


            }

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

I even tried to make the painting more direct and primitive by making a single if statement for each scenario but, once the program runs , it does not paint correctly on the second and third line. or if I click space 2,2 (the last one on the grid) it does not paint until i click somewhere else...

Comment: Where is your call to `EndPaint`?

Comment: Also, unless there is something logically wrong with the actual paint code, what you posted is not enough with respect to Windows message processing.  We don't see if you called `DefWindowProc` for unprocessed messages, we don't know where `WM_PAINT` processing ends, etc.  You make a mistake in processing messages, then all sorts of weird or undesired effects can happen, regardless of how flawless the paint code may look.

Comment: I Used block because the grid is a symetrical 333 * 333 ... the cxBlock and cyBlock are been used only for activators to change the booleans. would this really be an issue? in testing every 'box' in the grid returns what they should to the booleans.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie added the entire wndprc

Comment: I always find it useful to create some template RAII wrappers for CloseHandle, EndPaint etc..

Comment: Wait, did you abandon the problem of centering the grid last time?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing what you see? Your code won't compile as is and it's hard to work out what your actual problem is from your description.

Comment: Where is the code that triggers a repaint when you toggle the value of a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call SelectObject to select a suitable pen into the DC or else LineTo will randomly use whatever pen was leftover there (which might be invisible or something).

Comment: Don't forget a brush too.